# Use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} without attaching the query string to the new address

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to do a 301 redirect with .htaccess.

The issue:

```
/?view=products&id=12345 -> /8831
```

there is no relation between the old and the new address.

For some reason

```
Redirect 301 /?view=products&id=12345 /8831
```

doesn't work. If I remove the question mark, it works without question mark.

i tried also:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&id=12345
RewriteRule .*$ /8831 [L,R=301]
```

but it redirects me to `/8831?view=products&id=12345`, which is not good for me. I don't need the query string in the new url-

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&id=12345 
RewriteRule .*$ /8831? [L,R=301]
```

The ending `?` will prevent the original query parameters from being appended, unless you also give the `[QSA]` flag again.

From [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Note: Query String
>   The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string, containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string, to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. ***When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.*** To combine a new query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag.