# htaccess redirect with GET parameters - 2 parameters but dont need the second param

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a URL with 2 parameters but need to redirect it to a new page with a cleaner URL.

The old URL is `https://example.com/homes-for-sale-results/?city=Delta&propertyType=SFR%2CCND` The first parameter (`city=Delta`) is the only one that needs to match – any other parameters afterwards shouldn't have an effect on the redirect.

I am wanting it to redirect to `https://example.com/listings/pageid-89/city-Ladner/` regardless of what comes after `https://example.com/homes-for-sale-results/?city=Delta`

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} city=Delta
RewriteRule ^/homes-for-sale-results(.*)?$ http://example.com/listings/pageid-89/city-Ladner/ [R=301]
```

However this does not work but instead redirects to `https://example.com/residential-properties/our-sold-listings/?city=Delta&propertyType=SFR,CND`

Does anyone know a way I could fix this?

Comment: As there's nothing in the provided configuration about `our-sold-listings` you are obviously not providing the whole picture here. IIRC the query string is always passed through a rewrite unless you suffix the destination with `?`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277182/use-rewritecond-query-string-without-attaching-the-query-string-to-the-new-ad

Comment: _"However this does not work but instead redirects to"_ - this should not redirect anywhere, because your RewriteRule pattern doesn't match to begin with. When configured in .htaccess, the local path it matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off already at this point.